# Google Cloud Platform: Multiple *website.com in one project or per each website per project?

Tags: web, cloud, google-cloud-platform, platform

Is it ideal to put *.website.com into one GCP project or have one project per website? We are going to use Firebase to store the backend data, and the data between each *.website.com will be shared.

Any tips or more efficient ways to get a website started/hosted onto Google Cloud Platform? (So much stuff/information it is quite overwhelming)

Answer (score 3):

Best practices is usually to have a site per project so you can keep all your website related resources in a single project. Otherwise you'll have a lot of resources in a project going to different websites that will make it harder to maintain.

Alternatively if you are hosting multiple websites on the same infrastructure then you could consider a project per environment e.g staging, development etc.

Another possibility that some people use is put all front end resources in a project and then all the backend resources in another project and use googles cross project networking to communicate with them as this allows team separation of resources.

I'd need to know a little more about what you are trying to set up.

Answer (score 0):

The most *cost effective* way of hosting static (HTML) websites and/or shared website content on Google Cloud Platform is to store it in a **Cloud Storage** bucket. Since Cloud Storage comes with an always free tier, this can save a lot of money over time. See this article for details on hosting it on Cloud Storage https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website

I run many websites and domains on one project. Projects have more to do with permissions and billing than serving website content, which really has more to do with DNS records; but if your site is running on App Engine, only one app can run per project.